# Van der Waerden type numbers (for geometric progressions)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

Van der Waerden theorem is true also for geometric progressions. 
Is there anything interesting in van der Waerden type numbers $ W'(r,k) $ derived from this version? ($ W'(r,k) $ is such that if the integers $ \{1, 2, ..., W'(r,k)\} $ are colored, each with one of r different colors, then there are at least k integers in geometric progression all of the same color). Probably there is some obvious connections between $ W'(r,k) $ and $ W(r,k) $. Is there any literature about this topic?

Comment: http://joelmoreira.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/double-van-der-waerden/

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this, there are some facts about van der Waerden theorem for geometric progression, but there's nothing about "van der Waerden geometric numbers".

Comment: It may very well be that no results on this are known. There is a book by Bruce Landman: Ramsey theory on the integers which contains a lot of information on variants of the van der Waerden theorem. It doesn't talk about geometric progressions though. As far as I am aware, Prof Landman works on similar problems. Maybe you can find his email address and email him.

Comment: I was myself interested in the problem so I posted it on mathoverflow. The complete solution as far as geometric numbers are concerned is found in the comments there. Please see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142777/geometric-van-der-waerden-theorem